# Javascript window.location.replace() does not redirect the web page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a very simple script where window.location.replace() or window.location.assign() not working.

```
  function chartquery(){
    ticker=document.getElementById("queryticker").value;
    document.getElementById("queryticker").value =  ticker;
    jumptourl="http://127.0.0.1:5000/chart/"+ticker;
    alert(jumptourl);
    window.location.replace(jumptourl);
  }
```

the HTML form is here:

```
 <form class="form-search" onsubmit="chartquery()">
    <input id="queryticker" type="text" class="input-medium search-query" style="text-transform:uppercase"  placeholder="AAPL" size="10" onfocus="this.value=''">
 </form>
```

When I enter AAPL in the form and press enter, the function window.location.replace(jumptourl) does seem to force the browser to do some kind of http request but the new page does not jump to the "jumpurl" but just stay on the old url (http://127.0.0.1:5000/chart/MSFT) with a new "?" added at the end (http://127.0.0.1:500/chart/MSFT?).

I must be doing some very silly.

Comment: Your `<form>` is submitting, and because it has no `action` attribute the default behavior is for it to reload the page.

Comment: In function after submitting the form you should use something like event.preventDefault() because otherwise after sending form, the page will reload itself. As @Pointy said.

Comment: function chartquery(event) {
event.preventDefault(); /* rest of the code */
}

Comment: Change `replace` to `assign`

Comment: Thanks both. I though the js will get executed anyway no matter what action it is being taken. I thought whatever js script inside the onsubmit function will override everything. Anyway, I tried adding a action="javascript:void(0);" in the form, it works now!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my form has no action="something". after changing the form to the following

```
<form class="form-search" onsubmit="chartquery()" action="javascript:void(0);">
```

it works just fine now.
Also I should change from window.location.replace to window.location.assign if I want to add the new url request to the browser history.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this way to redirect a page is...

````
// more ways
window.location.replace('my-next-page.php')
window.location.assign('my-next-page.php')
document.location.href = 'my-next-page.php' ```
````